# Registered app principal stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I have registered an app principal in one of our sites using "appregnew.aspx" and gave permissions using "appinv.aspx". I'm using this app's client ID and client secret in a console job which was running fine for few months till now.

The job suddenly started failing and I see the below error message from TokenHelper.cs -

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException was caught
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Token request failed.
>     Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions
>     StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
>          at SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm) in c:\Users\v6urbn\Desktop\Raghav\Dev\CIM\SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM\SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM\TokenHelper.cs:line 355
>          at SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM.SyncBPM.StartSync() in c:\Users\v6urbn\Desktop\Raghav\Dev\CIM\SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM\SFMO.CIM.SPToBPM\SyncBPM.cs:line 47
>     InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>               at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse()
>               at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
>          InnerException:

And this is how I create the `ClientContext` -

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri(config.SiteUrl);
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);
string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
{
}
```

I've tried providing the permissions again for the app principal and it did not work. If I generate a new app principal with permissions and use it in the job it is working fine.

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the issue. It looks like the client secret generated for a client ID expires after one year.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in

A new client ID should be re-generated and assigned to this client ID.